polars: how to optimize sink_parquet
I'm working on string manipulation in large files which is explained here.  Based on the recommendations I received, I am using LazyFrames and the sink_parquet function.
As I try to improve throughput I want to optimize the sink_parquet function.
One of sink_parquet function  parameters is row_group_size.  In my case I'm ingesting a 78M row parquet file using pl.scan_parquet().  The file info shows there are 40 row_groups.  The sink_parquet function has a parameter row_groups described as follows:

row_group_size:
Size of the row groups in number of rows. If None (default), the chunks of the DataFrame are used. Writing in smaller chunks may reduce memory pressure and improve writing speeds.

My questions:

does it make sense to try to optimize the sink_parquet; and if so
does the function calculate the row_group size from the file information ie. # of rows/# of row_groups and if not, what flexibility do I have in what I specify; or
if I accept the default, what are the DataFrame chunks (esp. since the input is a LazyFrame). There is no 'memory pressure' as the process is only consuming ~5G of and available ~128G so there is room for larger chunks if that can be done.

I've looked and found this and looked here for clues but not come up with anything.
Update:
Experiments on a 600K row data set were not promising.  I varied the row_group_size over a range of 30-100% of total rows but there was very little difference in overall processing time or memory consumption.  There was a significant increase in CPU usage at the smaller number of rows.  I've observed CPU use is high (~95-100%) during parquet writes so small row_group_size means more frequent writing.

I'm not sure if it's in response to this question, but I did notice https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/16073 in the PR queue. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/16071 was also part of today's release (0.20.24)
